# Automatic Sorting by Date

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, filter, filtering

So I was trying to sort my some data in one of my sheets in ascending order automatically using google scripts. I created this script, and for some reason it does nothing.

```
function Filter() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Waitlist'),
      range = sheet.getRange("A7:H");

  range.sort(1);
}
```

Could someone take a look at this and give me some insight as to why the sort isn't working.

Comment: Welcome. The question hasn't enough details to reproduce the problem. Please add sample data and a link to demo spreadsheet that includes the minimal of data, sheets, formula and code required to observe the problem. Ref. [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function Filter() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Waitlist')
  range=sheet.getRange("A7:H");
  range.sort({column:1,ascending:true});
}
```

- [range.sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))

Comment: Hey Cooper. I tried this and it still doesn't sort anything.  Like the function works, but nothing happens like last time. Do you happen to have any other ideas?

Comment: Ok it worked. It was just a problem on my end. Thank you!